# How to get a list of all Embed values?

Tags: c#, linq, openxml

I have a docx file with multiple pictures. The document.xml looks like this (multiple times):

```
 .... 
 <w:drawing>
        <a:blip r:embed="rId12">
     ....
        </a:blip>
</w:drawing>
```

how can I get a list of the embed-values with LINQ?

I have this,which does not work :

```
string[] imageIds =                   
   (string[]) (from drawing in docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Drawing>()
    where drawing.Descendants<A.Blip>().First<A.Blip>() != null
    select drawing.Descendants<A.Blip>().First().Embed.Value);
```

Comment: No explanation of what actually `docx` is and whether it should be used in an answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
XNamespace a = "http://youranamespaceurl.com";
XNamespace r = "http://yourrnamespaceurl.com";
var embedes = from el in docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants(a + "blip")
select (string)el.Attribute(r + "embed")
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you

Comment: .Attribute is red underlined in VS2013. blip has no member function "Attribute"